# Obtaining body string from API instead of header

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I've tried to write a method expected to return the API's response to me. But, when I call its return value in `Console.WriteLine`, I get its header. Additionally, I think to obtain its output which may include unicode characters in `UTF-8`.

If there is better way to get it in the encoding, I'm glad to hear that.

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Test(string apiUrl, string apiKey)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), apiUrl))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept",        "application/json");
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", apiKey);

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            /*
            string message      = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    string parsedString = Regex.Unescape(message);
                    byte[] isoBites     = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(parsedString);
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(isoBites, 0, isoBites.Length);
            */

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

What I get is the following,

```
 allow: GET,POST 
 cache-control: no-cache 
 connection: keep-alive 
 content-length: 146870 
 content-security-policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:; 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Thu, 16 Jan 2020 12:52:47 GMT 
 expires: -1
```

What I expect is its body which yields some JSON string like,

```
[{"MemberNo": 62,"MemberName": "comp1","PrefixNo": 545102,
"IsBusinessCard": false,"Brand": null,"LogoUrl": null},{"MemberNo":   62,"MemberName": 
"comp2","PrefixNo": 554796,"IsBusinessCard": false,"Brand":
null,"LogoUrl": null}]
```

Comment: your question is unclear ... *But, it returns its header.*  no, it returns `HttpResponseMessage` class that's how you wrote it,  *I think to obtain its output which may include* ... good for you ... we don't have access to the api so we don't know if you think wrong or right

Comment: @Selvin you're absolutely right. Due to my being busy, I couldn't think properly.

Comment: *What I get is similar to the following,* ... this is what `HttpResponseMessage.ToString()`  returns ... what's you expected?

Comment: @Selvin I expect its body. I mean it returns JSON string like, {"message":"Action '' here we are","success":false}.

Comment: Your API gives you the response to your request. This includes the headers, status code, etc. The way the method is written now, it's the caller’s job to extract the body text.  Note that the body is not shown by the response’s ToString() because typically you can only read the body stream once. Consider setting `DefaultRequestHeaders` on your `HttpClient` and then calling the `GetStringAsync()` method to avoid having to deal with request and response objects yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The following yields what I wish.

```
var http = Test(url, key); // calling function
var json_string = http.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(json_string);
```

Comment: @Selvin what if I don't want to go on execution after a while? e.g. in the case of `http.Result.StatusCode` is not `200`.

Comment: call `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` and catch exception

Comment: Why call exception while I can handle it by usüng if-else?

Comment: ... ifs you say ...[ok just count how many ifs you should do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the body from the respone content.

```
    if (response.Content != null)
    {
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Trace.WriteLine(responseBody);;                            
    }
```

Comment: he has alread `string message      = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` in commented code :) ... so it's unclear what he is asking about

Comment: @Selvin that's probably becuase my ignorance on request/response terms. But, I think I'm clear. I need "body". What I get already is "headers".

Comment: @Selvin I figured out a while ago as can be seen in my answer.